# How to retrieve the Font of word from RichTextBox in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, richtextbox

I am developing an app in WinForms using C#. It has a small window that includes a RichTextBox. The user can write in the RichTextBox and by pressing ctrl+b and ctrl+i they can change the font to bold or italic. When the application is closed down the text is saved. When the application is restarted the text is stored into the RichTextBox again. The problem is I cannot store the font the user was writing with. If a user had a word in bold for example, after the app restarts the word is not bold anymore. Is there a way to store the state of a word ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [RTF property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf.aspx) of the RichTextBox returns the formatted text, so that's what you need to store:

> You can use this property .. to extract the text of the control with
>   the specified RTF formatting defined in the text of the control.

Comment: I can see that the RichTextBox.RTF brings back the text that indicates what RTF property each word has. Is there any smart way to extract it word by word? Or i need to split the text returned by RichTextBox.RTF and take it from there?

Comment: can you give some more info about what you're trying to do? Why do you need to parse the RTF?

Comment: I have a rich text box. In this text box, the user can for example press **ctrl+b** or **ctrl+i** to make text bold or italic. When the user closes the App the text he had in the RichTextBox is stored in an XML file. Next time the user opens the app, the app will look at the XML file and if there is a text in it it will restore it to the RichTextbox.
I want to store what fomat exha word has as well. So if a user wrote **Book** in italic, I can restore it into the rich textbox as italic as well.

Comment: We're going round in circles here. If you store the value of the RTF property in the file and then restore it, the formatting will be preserved.

Comment: You were absolutely right, it works now. Thank you so so much!!

Comment: Glad to help. You can mark this as an answer to your question by clicking the tick next to it.

Answer (score 0):

As @stuartd mentioned the [RTF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf.aspx) propert can be used to solve the aforementioned problem. I store the **`myRichTextBox.Rtf`** property in a string and then in a file. After app restarts I read the file and assign the read value to **`myRichTextBox.Rtf`** .